# Italics in book title (Solved)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, italic, bibliographystyle

I'm trying to change the bibliography style of my document using `natbib` and `bibtex`, but none of the styles display italics in book titles. For example, [dinat](https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-dinat-dinat/) uses italics for them according to the webpage (and the bst file), but they don't show up in my document:

foo.tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,spanish]{book}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{beton} % This package was the problem

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\nocite{cutland:book89}
\bibliography{bibliografia}
\end{document}
```

bibliografia.bbl:

```
@Book{cutland:book89,
  author =   {One, Some},
  title =    {b},
  publisher =    {c},
  year =     1989}
```

Result:
[image: Result]

(Note that the style does change, just not the italics.)

Comment: Please post a full MWE, not just snippets of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the package `beton` was interfering with the font styles. Since I don't need it, I deleted the line `\usepackage{beton}` here:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,spanish]{book}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{beton}

\begin{document}
foo
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\cite{cutland:book89}
\bibliography{bibliografia}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, a fuller texlive installation provides all the fonts in that package, which includes italics.